# Parshape doesn't work

Tags: formatting, paragraphs, wrap

I know that wrapping picrures is frequent question here, and all of my quetions here are about it.

But new day is a new probem.

Look at the screenshots...

You will get this if you run my code

[image]

This result you will get, if you change `\dimexpr(-0.25\textwidth-2mm)` in the last `\parshape` option-line to `0pt`
[image]

But in my code for some reasons `0pt` doesn't work for the first two lines!

Can you explain and fix that?

I want first two lines to behave like on the second screenshot and the third line -- like on the first screenshot. (it's obvious, I guess)

```
\documentclass[a5paper,9pt]{extbook}
    \usepackage[margin=1.6cm, top=1.2cm,right=1.6cm,left=2.3cm, footskip = 1 cm, headheight=20pt,headsep=0.2cm,showframe]{geometry}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \usepackage{mwe}
        \usepackage{xargs}        
        \input{insbox.tex}
        \usepackage{threeparttable}


    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

    \newcommandx\addpictureR[4][1=0,3=0]{
    \InsertBoxR{#3}{\begin{threeparttable}%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}%
    \captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]}

    \begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \addpictureR{example-image-a}{1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(0.8\textwidth-2mm)}
    \begin{thm}[Cauchy]
    \label{abc2}
    em\\em\\em
    \begin{equation}
    \label{abc3}
    \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
    \end{equation}
    \parshape 3 
0pt \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
0pt \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
\dimexpr(-0.25\textwidth-2mm) \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
    jajajajajaja\\tytytytyty\\hohohohohoh.
    \end{thm}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Theorems are typeset using a `list` environment, which also sets `\parshape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this (you can only change `\parshape` at the start of a paragraph, but the whole construct seems massively over-complicated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,9pt]{extbook}
    \usepackage[margin=1.6cm, top=1.2cm,right=1.6cm,left=2.3cm, footskip = 1 cm, headheight=20pt,headsep=0.2cm,showframe]{geometry}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \usepackage{changepage}
        \usepackage{mwe}
        \usepackage{xargs}        
        \input{insbox.tex}
        \usepackage{threeparttable}


    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

    \newcommandx\addpictureR[4][1=0,3=0]{
    \InsertBoxR{#3}{\begin{threeparttable}%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}%
    \captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]}

    \begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \addpictureR{example-image-a}{1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(0.8\textwidth-2mm)}
    \begin{thm}[Cauchy]
    \label{abc2}
    em\\em\\em
    \begin{equation}
    \label{abc3}
    \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
    \end{equation}

    \parshape 3 
0pt \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
0pt \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
\dimexpr(-0.25\textwidth) \dimexpr\textwidth+0.25\textwidth+2mm\relax
    jajajajajaja\\tytytytyty\\hohohohohoh.
    \end{thm}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my God, All that I need - it is just to press *Enter*... Thank a bunch. How could I guess about this Enter?

Comment: @Dida an equation is _part of_ a paragraph. (and counts as three lines) for parshape etc.

Comment: Yeah, I know about 3 lines, but I was sure that `parshape` begins new paragraph... Oh, I need a rest. Thank you.